# removing : from the name of the figure latex (Fig. 4.2: to Fig. 4.2 )

Tags: latex

I tried to remove `:` from the name of figures and tables but unfortunately, it doesn't work. I'm using the caption package.

```
begin{figure}[H]

\hspace*{-1cm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Images/w9.jpg}
        \caption{Architecture of IoT-Blockchain}
        \label{fig:w5}
    \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `labelsep=...` option of the caption package to replace the colon with a space:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\chapter{title}

\section{title}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\caption{Architecture of IoT-Blockchain}
\label{fig:w5}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work, I feel that I have other libraries that influence the result

Comment: @mesh123456 Then you should post a [mre] and not let people guess which packages you might or might not use!